# How to wire this component (-4dB audio)

Tags: audio, dc, line

Getting frustrated because I don't understand what this -4dB thing is in the circuit and I can't figure out how to wire it correctly or even if I have the right part. I have a 3.5mm mono audio jack but I'm not sure what -4dB means. I've tried looking up some videos on how to build this circuit but the ones I've found were pretty poorly made and didn't clearly show how this was supposed to get wired. The audio jack I'm using has 3 prongs. The wiring diagram only shows one connection. Where do I connect the other prongs?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The -4dB refers to the voltage at the output. You can completely ignore it as it's pretty much meaningless unless you're working with professional audio equipment.

The only part you are interested in is the phrase "Line Output" and this indicates to you that it is a "line level" audio signal - i.e., one suitable for connecting to the "Line Input" port of an amplifier or similar piece or audio equipment (i,e, it can't directly drive a speaker, it needs an amplifier).

You connect the "-4dB Line Output" to the center pin ("tip") of your jack, and the outside "sleeve" to ground.  If there is a middle "ring" pin that can be connected to the "-4DB Line Output" as well.

[image]

Comment: So I can't use the audio jack that I have then?

Comment: Yes you can - see the edit I was writing at the same time you were commenting.

Comment: Okay awesome. Thanks. I will give this a shot and select that as the answer if it works. Thanks again.